# error while connecting remote server using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, python

I am trying to access remote server: Here is my ssh command given below-

```
bitech@hdpedge01:~/.ssh$ ssh techniker@151.252.41.105 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -v
```

I am getting permission denied error:

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u6, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 151.252.41.105 [151.252.41.105] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/bitech/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bitech/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: DSA 28:64:63:b2:91:98:78:db:f9:4f:b3:32:f1:a4:39:27
debug1: Host '151.252.41.105' is known and matches the DSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/bitech/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_dss_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bitech/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/bitech/.ssh/id_rsa':
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/bitech/.ssh/id_rsa':
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/bitech/.ssh/id_rsa':
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I do not understand how to debug this error. I have tried to change the passphrase using `ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -p` command but it always give me Bad `passphrase error`.

Comment: It's unclear what you tried to get this authentication working.  I read it twice and wonder if you're trying to configure the wrong machine.  Do you have access to the remote server to fix its configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The errors say that what you are trying to open is not recognized as a private key that could OpenSSH read.

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bitech/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/bitech/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

There is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2522), that will be fixed in the next release. In short, OpenSSH of certain versions represents all errors as a "wrong passphrase", which can be very confusing for users.

How does your key look like? Where did you get that from?